# keep the $_SESSION variable alive during auto-refresh

Tags: php, html, tags, meta

I have a question with my coding about keeping the session variable alive during autorefresh.
so I have a page that generates its methods with the value grabbed from the previos page with this,

```
$_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] = $_POST['cd-dropdown'];
```

all the methods are using this variable $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']. 
When I press reload on the page, the variable still alive. the problem arises when I do autorefresh with meta tag .

after each refresh the variables disappears that make all the methods don't work.

so please help me on how to approach this with autorefresh and keeping the variable alive.

thanks a lot

Comment: I think $_SESSION variable is OK, and you are loosing $_POST value. Try this if(isset( $_POST['cd-dropdown'])) $_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] = $_POST['cd-dropdown'];

Comment: @jtorrescr so you mean that all the methods have to be wrapped inside the if branch ?

Comment: Al values you are getting from $_POST and you are putting in the $_SESSION